# Django DeleteView JavaScript confirmation

Tags: javascript, django

I need to use JS confirmation instead of django's HTML confirm. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542388/django-class-based-view-deleteview-how-to-disable-confirmation-requirement) I found a solution of my problem, but there is no code example. Please, help and give me some code.
Here is my View:

```
class EmployeeDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Employees
    template_name = "employees_confirm_delete.html"
    success_url = "/"
```

And here is model:

```
class Employees(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
```

And here is a part of URL, that deletes an object: `/employee/{{ object.id }}/delete`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code, that will do it.

But first, make sure, that you have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings.py file. It is there by default and this will protect from csrf attacks.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('main.views',
    # ...
    url(r'^employee/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', EmployeeDelete.as_view(), name='delete_employee'),
    # ...
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import  DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson as json


class EmployeeDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Employees
    template_name = "employees_confirm_delete.html"
    success_url = "/"

    # allow delete only logged in user by appling decorator
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # maybe do some checks here for permissions ...

        resp = super(EmployeeDelete, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            response_data = {"result": "ok"}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json")
        else:
            # POST request (not ajax) will do a redirect to success_url
            return resp
```

**some template, where links to delete employee are present (look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) for ajax csrf protection)**

```
{% for e in employees %}
    <a class="delete" href="{% url 'delete_employee' e.id %}"> Delete employee {{e.id}}</a>
{% endfor %}

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        // This function must be customized
        var onDelete = function(){
            $.post(this.href, function(data) {
                if (data.result == "ok"){
                    alert("data deleted successfully");
                } else {
                    // handle error processed by server here
                    alert("smth goes wrong");
                }
            }).fail(function() {
                // handle unexpected error here
                alert("error");
            });
            return false;
        }

        $(".delete").click(onDelete);
    });
</script>
```

You just need to customize the behaviour of `onDelete` js function.

Comment: You can use something like http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/ for the confirmation (or code it yourself with javascript/jquery)